# Service Stack JsonApiClient change base url

Tags: servicestack

I'm using service stack JsonAPiclient to login and manage auth.

can't seem to figure out how to change baseurl after logging in.
var client = new JsonApiClient(baseUri);

my auth url is different than my normal api url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the issue is, you initialize which **BaseUrl** to use with creating a client instance:

```cs
var client = new JsonApiClient(baseUri);
```

I'd recommend creating a new instance instead of mutating the BaseUrl after initialization, but it can be changed with:

```cs
client.SetBaseUri(newBaseUri);
```

Comment: ending up doing a PostToUrl and not change or create a new instance.